# What's the root of this chord progression

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

I've encountered a chord progression, but I'm not quite sure to which key it belongs (I discovered it by playing around on a guitar). The chord progression sounds like this: `Amadd9 Em/G F#7add11`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember **root** is not the same as **key**. You've used both words in your question.

The root of an Amadd9 chord is A. The root note of an Em/G chord is E, because the chord is simply an Em chord, but not in root position. [In classical music this chord would be called *E minor, first inversion*.] The root note of F#7add11 is F#.

As for key: your first two chords suggest we are in A minor, but we've only heard the notes C, E, G, A and B so far and we could equally be in C major. And until we hear an F of some sort we might equally be in E minor or G major.

Your third chord introduces an F# and a C# which suggest we're moving away from A minor in a 'sharpwards' direction. So far your progression doesn't 'belong' to any key. It hasn't yet established one. This doesn't matter of course, if you're happy with it. You could play alternate chords of A minor and D minor all day without establishing a key.